# What does Preload function do in gorm?

Tags: go, go-gorm

The link http://gorm.io/docs/preload.html talks about preloading in GORM, but I am unable to understand what this function does.

```
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Username string
  Orders Order
}
type Order struct {
  gorm.Model
  UserID uint
  Price float64
}


db.Preload("Username")

db.Preload("Orders").Find(&users)
```

Can someone explain what will these 2 statements do? What will be the output ?

Is it that `preload` is used to cache the results?

Comment: I am not from Go ecosystem deeply. I am familiar with this term from Java ecosystem. I would say that, it is for performance issues. There are two terms. Eager loading and Lazy loading. Lazy Loading means related entities are not loaded, until we need them. Eager Loading is the process where a query for one type of entity also loads related entities as a part of the query. It uses more memory. But less computation for other calls. Hope it is clear.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

First of all, this doesn't really do anything:

```
db.Preload("Username")
```

On the other hand, the following:

```
db.Preload("Orders").Find(&users)
```

Does do something. First it populates `users` and then it populates `[]user.Orders`. On the comments on the page you linked you will find this, which shows what it does by query:

```
db.Preload("Orders").Find(&users)
//// SELECT * FROM users;
//// SELECT * FROM orders WHERE user_id IN (1,2,3,4);
```

So what does this really do? I can give you the technical answer, which you can easily find out by googling **eager loading** or I can give you an answer by example which I feel is simpler.

So let me explain this by example.

Say you have users, where each user can have multiple orders. This is a one to many relationship which can be defined like:

```
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Username string
  Orders []Order
}
```

When you populate your `users` slice like:

```
db.Find(&users)
//// SELECT * FROM users;
```

If you need to get all the orders for each user you can easily access `user.Orders` but this would be empty anyway because it didn't get populated.

If we populate `users` slice like:

```
db.Preload("Orders").Find(&users)
```

The `user.Orders` will be populated by the orders of that user. This is an abstraction that makes dealing with relationships easier.

The ugly alternative would be:

```
db.Find(&users)

for user := range users {
  db.Where("user_id", user.id).Find(&user.Orders)
}
```

It will also make more request to the database than necessary. (which is not good)

If your users has Posts and Comments and Orders then you can define and query it like this:

```
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Username string
  Orders []Order
  Comments []Comment
  Posts []Post
}

db.Preload("Orders").Preload("Comments").Preload("Posts").Find(&users)
```

With just the code above you can now have access to the users data in different tables in the database.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I have a question. If, for example, the orders table has another nested table inside it, how do you preload it? Should I just chain it the same way as the others? Is this `db.Preload("Orders").Preload("TableInsideOrders").Find(&users)` correct?

Comment: @arahpanah that is incorrect - on the gorm docs for Preload you'll see the following
```db.Preload("Orders.OrderItems").Find(&users)```

Comment: it is still unclear to me where the user ids came from. is that a list of all user ids found? from the example it looks like preload just joins on the specified foreign keys

Comment: "The link you provided shows what it does. You just have to actually read the information on the page." snarky and unnecessary. I came from that exact page needing further clarification and examples.